# Фокус в элементах при открытом Bootstrap Modal

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

[Есть **демка**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtPY4/6/), в которой показывается открытие одного модала поверх другого. В правом верхнем углу я добавил текстовое поле. Проблема с тем, что в это текстовое поле не ставится фокус (и каретка не появляется) по клику на него, если открыт модал.

Причем я заметил такую особенность. Сначала когда открываю первый модал - фокус не ставится. Когда открываю второй модал (кнопка "Open FG modal"), то фокус начинает ставится. После закрытия второго модала фокус продолжает ставится в поле.

Задача: **сделать так, чтобы всегда можно было поставить фокус в текстовое поле, если открыт модал.**

P.S. Спрашиваю не для любопытства, это смоделированная ситуация в моем приложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина такого поведения - `tabindex="-1"`, но если его убрать, то не срабатывает закрытие по esc, в общем я смог починить только по click

```
$('.fixed').bind('click.$',function() {$(this).focus();});
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/95wke/)